# JAXB binding to generate an abstract Java class from a non-abstract XML type

Tags: xml, binding, jaxb, xjc

### In short

Is there any JAXB binding that can tell the JAXB code generator to generate a Java class as `abstract` *without having to mark the corresponding XML type as `abstract` in the XSD*?

### Description

The situation is as follows:

- I define a schema in XSD: `mySchema.xsd`
- I use inline JAXB bindings ("inline" == "directly in the schema") to indicate the package where the JAXB classes should be generated (`my.package.jaxb`):

  ```
  <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
          <jxb:schemaBindings>
              <jxb:package name="my.package.jaxb"/>
          </jxb:schemaBindings>
      </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  ```
- I use inline JAXB bindings to indicate the name of the implementation class for each of my complex types (in this example `my.package.impl.MyAbstractClass`, `my.package.impl.MyAClass` and `my.package.impl.MyBClass`):

  ```
  <xs:complexType name="myAbstractType" abstract="true">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
              <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyAbstractClass"/>
          </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      ...
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="myAType">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
              <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyAClass"/>
          </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="myAbstractType">
              ...
          </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="myBType">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
              <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyBClass"/>
          </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="myAbstractType">
              ...
          </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  ```
- I generate the JAXB class from the schema. This results in:

  ```
  my.package.jaxb
     |- MyAbstractType
     |- MyAType (extends MyAbstractClass)
     |- MyBType (extends MyAbstractClass)
  ```
- I write my own classes:

  ```
  my.package.impl
     |- MyAbstractClass (extends MyAbstractType)
     |- MyAClass (extends MyAType)
     |- MyBClass (extends MyBType)
  ```

The reason I do it like this, with these 2 class hierarchies, is so that I can separate the generated code (`my.package.jaxb.*`) from the manual (`my.package.impl.*`). This way when there are changes in the XSD I can regenerate the `my.package.jaxb.*` classes and make a few changes in my manual `my.package.impl.*` classes to incorporate the new behaviour.

So far so good. The issue is that in `MyAbstractClass` I want to define an **abstract** method...

```java
protected abstract void doSomething();
```

...that is then implemented differently by `MyAClass` and `MyBClass`.
However, the generated `MyAType` and `MyBType` classes now have compilation errors because *they are not declared as abstract but they now inherit an abstract method* (notice that they both extend `MyAbstractClass`).

I cannot declare them as abstract in the XSD (`abstract="true"`) because doing so would result in the following error whenever I declare an element of type `myAType` or `myBType` in an XML:

```
cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot be abstract for element someElementName.
```

What I would like is to use some JAXB binding to tell the JAXB code generator to generate the classes `MyAType` and `MyBType` as `abstract` *without having to mark the XML types as `abstract`*. Is there such a binding? I haven't been able to find it so far.

Sorry for the long explanation, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a [XJC plugin](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html). Here's the code:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMods;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Options;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.ClassOutline;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Outline;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIDeclaration;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.XSAnnotation;

public class AbstractModifierPlugin extends com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin {

    private static final QName ABSTRACT_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/jaxb/abstract-modifier/1-0", "abstract");

    private static final String SET_FLAG_METHOD_NAME = "setFlag";

    private static final String OPTION_NAME = "Xabstract-modifier";

    @Override
    public String getOptionName() {
        return OPTION_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return " -" + OPTION_NAME + " : marks as abstract the generated classes corresponding to XML types marked with "
                + "<xs:annotation><xs:appinfo><" + ABSTRACT_QNAME + "/></xs:appinfo></xs:annotation>";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(Outline outline, Options options, ErrorHandler errorHandler) throws SAXException {
        Method setFlagMethod = null;
        try {
            // There is no method to make a class abstract; we can only use setFlag, which is private, so
            // we must get it via reflection and make it accessible.
            setFlagMethod = JMods.class.getDeclaredMethod(SET_FLAG_METHOD_NAME, int.class, boolean.class);
            setFlagMethod.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error retrieving the " + JMods.class.getName() + "." + SET_FLAG_METHOD_NAME
                    + " method (see below) => it will not be possible to set any class' abstract flag => this plugin will abort");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        for (ClassOutline classOutline : outline.getClasses()) {
            if (hasAbstractAnnotation(classOutline)) {
                try {
                    setFlagMethod.invoke(classOutline.implClass.mods(), JMod.ABSTRACT, true);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.err.println("It was not possible to make " + classOutline.implClass.fullName()
                            + " abstract (see below)");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean hasAbstractAnnotation(ClassOutline classOutline) {
        XSAnnotation annotation = classOutline.target.getSchemaComponent().getAnnotation();
        if (annotation != null) {
            Object innerAnnotation = annotation.getAnnotation();
            if (innerAnnotation instanceof BindInfo) {
                for (BIDeclaration bindInfoDeclaration : (BindInfo) innerAnnotation) {
                    if (ABSTRACT_QNAME.equals(bindInfoDeclaration.getName())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here's `abstract.xsd`, which defines the `<abstract>` element you need to use to indicate that the generated class should be abstract:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/jaxb/abstract-modifier/1-0"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/jaxb/abstract-modifier/1-0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="abstract"/>

</schema>
```

Usage (following the example in my original question):

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    ...
    xmlns:abstract="http://www.example.com/jaxb/abstract-modifier/1-0"
    ...>

    <xs:complexType name="myAbstractType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyAbstractClass"/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        ...
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="myAType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyAClass"/>
                <!-- This tells the AbstractModifierPlugin to make the
                generated class abstract -->
                <abstract:abstract/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="myAbstractType">
                ...
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="myBType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jxb:class implClass="my.package.impl.MyBClass"/>
                <!-- This tells the AbstractModifierPlugin to make the
                generated class abstract -->
                <abstract:abstract/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="myAbstractType">
                ...
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I have to say I found it pretty hard to find all the necessary documentation to figure out how to do this. If I find the time I will post a longer explanation here; for now I hope at least the code will help.
Disclaimer: I don't know whether this is the best way to do this but the classes I had to rely on are so loosely documented (and IMHO not very well designed) that that's the best I could come up with.

I hope this helps. If anyone wants to use this code, go ahead.

Comment: Is there no other way than using reflection?

Comment: @roded As indicated in my comments in the code above: _There is no method to make a class abstract; we can only use setFlag, which is private, so we must get it via reflection and make it accessible._ So AFAIK there is no alternative, but if you find one I'd be happy to hear about it.